# Decimal Truncating adding unlimited zeros

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an entry field for Xamarin forms. Where I have to store the value in a decimal field.

And as per the requirement I have to have the data in ##.#### format.

The validation that it should be less than hundred I am doing it with success.

However I have an issue when truncating the problem.

My Unfocused even for the entry field is as follows.

```
private void RateEntry_UnFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Entry)sender).Text))
    {
        ((Entry)sender).Text = "0.00%";
        _ProfileViewModel.Profile.Rate = (decimal)0.00;
    }
    else
    {
        _ProfileViewModel.Profile.Rate = Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(((Entry)sender).Text)* 10000)/10000;
        ((Entry)sender).Text = AddPercentageSymbol(_ProfileViewModel.Profile.Rate);
    }
    Validate();
}
```

for example if I give value as 99.9999 , I get the value as 99.99990000000000000%

Could you please help me to solve this issue.

**Edit: Function AddPercentageSymbol**

```
private string AddPercentageSymbol(decimal value)
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", value, "%");
}
```

**Edit: Expected Outputs**

```
99.9999 = 99.9999%
99.9999766 = 99.9999%
99.99 = 99.99% or 99.9900%
0.76433 = 0.7643%
```

Comment: What is the expected result if the input is `99.9999`?

Comment: Quick note: you can use `0.00m` instead of `(decimal) 0.00` to represent 0.00 as a `decimal` (and it will *actually* represent `0.00`, instead of just 0 which you're currently getting).

Comment: @ekad please find the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced this - it looks like it's simply a bug in Mono. It's very easily demonstrated:

```
decimal x = 9m;
decimal y = x / 10;
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

This should be "0.9", but it's actually "0.9000000000000000000000000000".

Please report a bug in Mono :)

The good news is that you can use `Math.Round` to get rid of excess digits, e.g.

```
decimal z = Math.Round(y, 2);
Console.WriteLine(z); // 0.90
```

Assuming you were multiplying by 10000, truncating, and then dividing by 10000 to round (down) to 4 digits, you should be able to get away with using `Math.Round(value, 4)` as by then the value won't have any significant digits after 4 decimal places anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the help but if I use the round my 99.9999 becomes 100, that is why I am trying not to do this.

Comment: @Fousana: I didn't suggest just calling `Math.Round(x)` - I suggested calling `Math.Round(x, 4)` which should round it *to four decimal places*.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, 99.9999 becomes 100 :(

Comment: @Fousana: I've just tested it, and it doesn't on my box: `Math.Round(99.9999m, 4)` results in 99.9999. How *exactly* are you calling `Math.Round`? Note that it's useful to split a multi-stage operation into several separate statements so that you can identify exactly which operation is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks let me try that again.